# How to use DELIMIDENT with IBM Informix ODBC Driver on Windows

Tags: sql, configuration, odbc, informix

Here is the query we are trying to run inside of SQLRunner over an IBM Informix ODBC Driver on a Windows system. The DB itself is hosted elsewhere.

```
SELECT keycolumnA AS 'Entity', datacol1, datacol2 WHERE keycolumnA IN ('ABC', 'DE f')
```

The query fails with *"ODBC Error"*

However, if we remove the quotes from *Entity*, the query works but the column name is returned in lower case. It is important that the first column be returned as **Entity** with the uppercase E.

We have tried setting the connection string as "DSN=myDSN; DELIMIDENT=y;" without success.

Setup: IBM Informix Driver version: 3.7 on Windows 2003.

Answer (score 1):

To be a delimited identifier, the name must be in double quotes, not single quotes.  So, with the connection string shown, writing the query as shown below 'should' work (famous last words):

```
SELECT keycolumnA AS "Entity", datacol1, datacol2
  FROM RandomlyNamedTable   -- NB: Not present in original query!
 WHERE keycolumnA IN ('ABC', 'DE f');
```

Tested on a database containing a table called Elements (storing data about the Table of Elements):

```
 SELECT Atomic_Number AS "Entity", Name AS Name, Symbol AS "Symbol"
  FROM Elements   -- NB: Not present in original query!
 WHERE Symbol IN ('Fe', 'He');

Entity  | name      | Symbol
INTEGER | CHAR(20)  | CHAR(3)
26      | Iron      | Fe
2       | Helium    | He
```

Note that the names 'Entity' and 'Symbol' are capitalized as you require.  When the double quotes were replaced by single quotes, the query failed

```
SELECT Atomic_Number AS 'Entity', Name AS Name, Symbol AS 'Symbol'
  FROM Elements   -- NB: Not present in original query!
 WHERE Symbol IN ('Fe', 'He');
SQL -201: A syntax error has occurred.
```

This was with DELIMIDENT set...without DELIMIDENT set, both single quotes and double quotes around the 'display labels' failed with a syntax error.

Testing against IBM Informix Dynamic Server 11.70.FC2 on Mac OS X 10.7.5.  (Program was written using ESQL/C, but that should be immaterial.)